# What are the pros and cons of single vs double sided magnets for magnet fishing?

Tags: magnet-fishing

There are two types of magnets sold for magnet fishing,

[Single sided](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073XMBQLP) with an eyelet on the top and the magnet directly below, and [double sided](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073Z4J5T8) with the eyelet on top of the circle and the magnets facing both directions.

What are the pros and cons of each type of magnet for magnet fishing?

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/21041/how-strong-of-a-magnet-is-needed-for-magnet-fishing-for-assorted-metal-objects

Comment: I'd think double would be more practical for tossing out into a lake/river and pulling back whereas single could be better for fishing off a pier where it is more a lower/raise situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be about your approach to the problem.

The doublesided magnet is going to be good for dragging, the single sided more for dangle and swing.

- If you have a bridge or pier over the water that you're fishing down from, the single sided will do nicely.
- If you're standing on the bank and want to fling the magnet out and draw it back to you then you would be better off with the double sided magnet, as the single sided would be on its edge and not make good contact with anything in the water.